# Performance with value semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I am very concerned about performance and readability of the code and I get most of my ideas from Chandler Carruth from Google. I would like to apply the following rules for C++ for clean code without loosing performance at all.

- Pass all Builtin types as values
- Pass all objects that you don't want to mutate by const reference
- Pass all objects that your function needs to consume by value
- Ban everything else. When in corner cases, pass a pointer.

That way, functions don't have side effects. That's a must for code readability and makes C++ kind of functionnal. Now comes performance. What can you do if you want to write a function that adds 1 to every element of a std::vector? Here is my solution.

```
std::vector<int> add_one(std::vector<int> v) {
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < v.size(); ++k) {
        v[k] += 1;
    }
    return v;
}

...
v = add_one(std::move(v));
...
```

I find this very elegant and makes only 2 moves. Here are my questions:

- Is it legal C++11 ?
- Do you think of any drawback with this design?
- Couldn't a compiler automatically transform v = f(v) into this? A kind of copy elision.

---

PS: People ask me why I don't like to pass by reference. I have 2 arguments:

1 - It's does not make explicit at the call site which argument might get mutated.

2 - It sometimes kill performance. References and pointers are hell for compiler because of aliasing. Let's take the following code

```
std::array<double, 2> fval(const std::array<double, 2>& v) {
    std::array<double, 2> ans;
    ans[0] = cos(v[0] + v[1]);
    ans[1] = sin(v[0] + v[1]);
    return ans;
}
```

The same code that takes ans as a reference is 2 times slower:

```
std::array<double, 2> fref(const std::array<double, 2>& v,
        std::array<double, 2>& ans) {
    ans[0] = cos(v[0] + v[1]);
    ans[1] = sin(v[0] + v[1]);
}
```

Pointer aliasing prevents the compiler from computing sin and cos with a single machine instruction (Gcc does not currently do that optimization, but icpc makes the optimization with value semantics).

Comment: Why would you pass all PODs as values? What if you had a POD with a huge array of `int`s in it? Or are you talking about builtin types, and not PODs in general? To add one to every element of a `vector` you should use `std::transform` and a lambda instead of your `add_one` function.

Comment: @Praetorian Changed the POD to builtin types. Add one is just an example, and some functions that are used to "mutate" objects are needed in my programs.

Comment: assuming your `add_one` function is modifying the copy vector that was passed to it rather than constructing a new one, you could std::move the return as well. If you are constructing a new one then NRVO would apply.

Of course move uses non-const r-value references, which by your rules above should be banned :)

Comment: Well, std::move is allowed ;-) The return is moved automatically at return as v is a local object in f

Comment: Sink values, ones that the value will be sucked in and modified, can be rvalues `&&`.  If your code took a `std::vector<int>&&` instead of one by-value, you'd force callers to "sink" their data into it.  As an example, `v = add_one(v);` passes all tests, yet has a completely useless huge vector copy hidden in it: your code compiles it.  With `vector&&` parameter, it now fails to compile.  Expensive operations should require extra work to happen: your coding style leads to making the operations cheap requiring extra work.

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't pass input by "const&" and output by pointer, is there a reason why you love return value so much?

Comment: Yakk@ I agree. But it has a huge benefit. There is now way to see that a function takes a reference instead of a value in C++ if you don't have the function signature in front of you. Here, it makes thing obvious with a std::move.

Comment: @InsideLoop No one can write code without consulting the documentation or function signatures of stuff they're using. So I disagree with passing by value for that reason. Yakk's suggestion will lead to a compilation error unless you use `std::move`, which your methodology doesn't. As for what to do with the return value, I think you want to `std::move` it. Usually that's discouraged because it inhibits copy/move elision, but I believe elision is not applicable to your use case anyway because you're mutating and returning the function argument.

Comment: Praetorian@ I'll check it but I really don't std::move is needed for the return. Anyway, on return the compiler should do copy elision, followed by a move assignment to v.

Comment: The design space is pretty wide here, but I tend to agree with Yakk that `add_one` should take its argument by rvalue reference given its current semantics. Silent performance degradation in apparently-reasonable code is bad. A similar design is also used for "actions" in ranges-v3.

Comment: TC@ Here you kind if get 2 functions for the price of one. If you want to mutate v, you can use std::move and if you want to keep the old value, just don't use it.

Comment: C++ really needs a `restrict` keyword.

Comment: @user3528438 Because pointers make compilers optimizers give up. Watch Chandler Carruth talks. He keeps saying that passing by reference is extremely bad performance wise. He knows what he is talking about, being on of the writer of LLVM. And I do have the same experience. Pointers and non const-references are just bad for perfomance. But most people think wrongly about them because they don't have a clue about optimizing compilers.

Comment: @user3528438 A restrict keyword that works with std::vector. Yes big times!

Comment: @InsideLoop About PS #2: can you show us some actual data? I get the same [results](http://goo.gl/kF5RIU)

Comment: @black which compiler do you use? Can you look at the assembly code? Does the value function calls cos then sin?

Comment: @black Your `f2` takes `ans` *by value*.

Comment: @black Really nice to have assembly output like that. It turns out Gcc 5.1 does a good job at using sincos when it can. Just change your code so that f2 takes ans by reference. In a snap, the sincos becomes cos, then sin. Very convincing.

Comment: @T.C. True, thanks. Turning on `fno-strict-aliasing` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be legal C++11 to me. Drawbacks may possibly be opinion-based so I won't address that, but as for your third point, the compiler could only do that transformation if it can prove that the function doesn't also alias `v` in any way. As such compiler writers may not have elected to implement such an optimization for the simple cases they can analyze and leave that burden (no-aliasing) on the programmer.

However also consider: When the function resists being written in a clear version with obvious performance characteristics perhaps you're writing the wrong function. Instead write an algorithm that operates on a range like the standard library and the problem goes away:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void add_one(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    for(; first != last; ++first)
    {
        (*first) += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are just passing a hidden pointer. Besides, I don't use iterator. What if the fonction you want to write wants to add each element of a vector to a given vector? Anyway, sometimes you want to mutate an object.

Comment: @InsideLoop, `std::vector` holds a hidden pointer, does it not? You'd have to eliminate a lot of code to be a purist.

Comment: @evan It even contains 3 of them ;-) One point. I just write numerical codes, so the only structure we know is std::vector. Therefore indexes are used in place of iterators.

Comment: @InsideLoop Iterators are fussy. Fortunately, with C++11 onward we got range-based for which makes the loop way cleaner and less error prone. BTW, whether you're using an index or an iterator, there's little difference.

Comment: @black: I work on numerical softwares where iterators are just not used. One of the reason for that is that we prefer to use struct of arrays over arrays of structs. Therefore, it is very common to have 2 std::vector a, b of the same length and you want to loop over a and b at the same time. Very easy with indices and unnatural with iterators. Moreover, indices are way more convenient: they don't get invalidated, you can program a binary search with them, etc. Iterators are useful is you work with structures which are not arrays. They introduce pain for people whose job only involves arrays.

Comment: @black: Moreover tools such as OpenMP are far more mature with indices.